# My database isn't connecting, sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlite, machine-learning, chatbot

I'm trying to connect a database to make a self learning chatbot. However, I keep getting this error,

```
line 8, in <module>
    connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I've looked over the location of the database and tried to rewrite it. However it is, to my knowledge, written correctly.

```
with open("/Users/name/Desktop/fileName/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
```

Below is where the error is saying I'm wrong at.

```
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2011-08'
sql_transaction = []

connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()
```

The date, '2011-08' is supposed to be part of the database file 'RC_2011-08'.

Comment: What is the name of the sqlite3 database file then? You are opening a file named `2011-08.db` in the *current working directory*. What directory is that here?

Comment: The file is RC_2011-08

Answer (score 1):

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
```

should be

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('RC_{}'.format(timeframe.split('-')[0]))
```

according to

```
with open("/Users/name/Desktop/fileName/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
```

^^ your format() has two parameters but you only use the first one...

timeframe becomes "2011" because of

```
timeframe.split('-')[0]
```